# Arraylist sorting in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, .net-2.0

I am trying to modify this code that already exists.The code was developed around 2008 and I am trying to fix the sort issue. I am also thinking of changing the code but wanted to fix the issue first.

```
ArrayList lineEmpNrs = new ArrayList();
taMibMsftEmpDetails employeeDetails; //taMibMsftEmpDetails is a custom class file

while (!HeaderFile.EndOfStream) //headerfile is employee information text file.
{
    headerRow = HeaderFile.ReadLine();
    headerFields = headerRow.Split(',');
    employeeDetails = BuildLine(headerFields[1],headerFields[2],headerFields[3]);
    lineEmpNrs.Add(employeeDetails);
}

 private taMibMsftEmpDetails BuildLine(string EmpId, string EmpName, String ExpnsDate)
 {
     taMibMsftEmpDetails empSlNr = new taMibMsftEmpDetails();
     empSlNr.EmployeeId  = EmpId;
     empSlNr.EmployeeName   = EmpName;
     empSlNr.ExpenseDate = ExpnsDate;
     return empSlNr;
 }
```

The Headerfile contains employee expense details. The empID is the key here and the headerFile can contain 'n' number of lines with same EmpID appearing in random order in the file.

I use lineEmpNrs to build some other information based on EmpID. So I want to have lineEmpNrs sorted based on EmpID. I tried the regular sort method but it didn't work.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you thought about using a `Generic List<T>` instead..?

Comment: What .Net version you have? Can you use LINQ?

Comment: The site is currently on .NET 2.0 but the code is very old. I thought of changing the code but this was some fix that I wanted to do as is. But if other options are better then I will rewrite.

Comment: What is the **exact** type of HeaderFile? FileStream? StreamReader?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: it is StreamReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is .Net 2.0 safe:

```
public static string ReadLines(StreamReader input)
{
    string line;
    while ( (line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
       yield return line;
}

private taMibMsftEmpDetails BuildLine(string EmpId, string EmpName, String ExpnsDate)
{
    taMibMsftEmpDetails empSlNr = new taMibMsftEmpDetails();
    empSlNr.EmployeeId  = EmpId;
    empSlNr.EmployeeName   = EmpName;
    empSlNr.ExpenseDate = ExpnsDate;
    return empSlNr;
}

List<taMibMsftEmpDetails> lineEmpNrs = new List<taMibMsftEmpDetails>();
foreach (string line in ReadLines(HeaderFile))
{
    headerFields = line.Split(',');
    lineEmpNrs.Add(BuildLine(headerFields[1],headerFields[2],headerFields[3]));
}
lineEmpNrs.Sort(delegate(taMibMsftEmpDetails a, taMibMsftEmpDetails a) 
   { 
      return a.EmployeeId.CompareTo(a.EmployeeId); 
   });
```

If you can get to at least .Net 3.5 (still uses .Net 2.0 runtime), it gets that much simpler:

```
public static string ReadLines(StreamReader input)
{
    string line;
    while ( (line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
       yield return line;
}

var lineEmpNrs = ReadLines(HeaderFile)
   .Select(l => l.Split(','))
   .Select(l => new taMibMsftEmpDetails() 
       {
          EmployeeId   = l[1],
          EmployeeName = l[2],
          ExpenseDate  = l[3]
       })
   .OrderBy(l=> l.EmployeeId)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: I am looking to find out record count based on employee. for example, empA record count is 99 and empB record count is 50 and so on. I had used this with Arraylist but want to know which option in LIST has this feature. Is GroupBy doable to acheive what I am looking for?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First - thus it is .Net 2.0 you can use strongly-typed generic list of type `List<taMibMsftEmpDetails>` instead of `ArrayList`:

```
List<taMibMsftEmpDetails> lineEmpNrs = new List<taMibMsftEmpDetails>();
// rest is same
```

Second - you can use method [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) with [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) delegate to sort employees by id:

```
lineEmpNrs.Sort(delegate(taMibMsftEmpDetails e1, taMibMsftEmpDetails e2) { 
                   return e1.EmployeeId.CompareTo(e2.EmployeeId); 
                });
```

Instead of anonymous method you can create usual named method for comparing employees:

```
lineEmpNrs.Sort(CompareEmployees);
```

Also consider to improve naming in your code. Consider to use `employees` collection instead of `lineEmpNrs`, `EmployeeDetails` class instead of `taMibMsftEmpDetails`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky-> I have tried your option and testing it now. Once I make lineEmpNrs as List, will I have option to find out how many times the same EmpID exists in the list. Basically I am looking to find out empA record count is 99 and empB record count is 50 and so on. I had used this with Arraylist but now I have to modify it as lineEmpNrs is list now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out below, this won't work on ArrayList, but you could convert `lineEmpNrs` to a `List<taMibMsftEmpDetails>`.

LINQ is perfect here.

```
var sortedList = lineEmpNrs.OrderBy(emp => emp.EmployeeId);
```

After seeing your comment, this will only work if you can bump your code from .NET 2.0 to 3.5 or higher.

Comment: heh, saw the folly as soon as I hit the submit answer button.  Thanks guys.

Comment: ArrayList doesn't I believe

Comment: `emp` is a variable you could name it anything you like look up lambda expressions when you get an opportunity

Comment: As @DJKRAZE mentions, yes,  do some research into Lambda expressions.  It's a placeholder variable that represents one item in the list of items that you are iterating through to order.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely: I don't get to see orderby when I type lineEmpNrs. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check my last line--I didn't realize you were working in 2.0.  LINQ was added in 3.5.  If you can switch your environment to .NET 3.5, you should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ArrayList as a List

```
var enumerableCollection = from taMibMsftEmpDetails ln in lineEmpNrs
                                        orderby ln.EmployeeId
                                        select ln;
```

You can convert to `Array` or use the `List`

Answer (score 1):

You can also load the data in to a DataTable and sort via a DataView.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("EmpID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Field2");
    dt.Columns.Add("Field3");

    // Read file, split values, add to table
    while (!HeaderFile.EndOfStream) {

        headerRow  = HeaderFile.ReadLine();
        headerFields = headerRow.Split(',');

        // Create row and add it to the table
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["EmpID"] = headerFields[0];
        dr["Field1"] = headerFields[1];
        dr["Field2"] = headerFields[2];
        dt.ImportRow(dr);
    }

    // Sort table by EmpID
    DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "EmpID ASC";
    dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular sort method should work alongside a custom compare method, something like the following:

```
private class sortByEmployeeIdHelper: IComparer
{
   int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
   {
       taMibMsftEmpDetails employeeA = (taMibMsftEmpDetails)a;
       taMibMsftEmpDetails employeeB = (taMibMsftEmpDetails)b;

       //employee id is numeric?
       int id = int.Parse(employeeA.EmployeeId);
       return id.CompareTo(int.Parse(employeeB.EmployeeId));
   }
}

IComparer myComparer = new sortByEmployeeIdHelper();
lineEmpNrs.Sort(myComparer);
```